# How is the equation $\tau_z=I_{zz}\alpha$ be satisfied for rotation about $z-$axis with $\tau_z\neq 0$ but $\tau_x=\tau_y=0$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Consider the rotational dynamics of a door. The door can rotate about a vertical axis passing through the hinges. Let us call it the $z-$axis so that $\vec{\omega}=\omega\hat{k}$. I want to consider the rotational dynamics of the door in the following manner.

The components of angular momentum of the door about a point O on the $z$-axis are $$L_x=I_{zx}\omega, L_y=I_{zy}\omega~~\text{and}~~L_z=I_{zz}\omega$$ where $I_{zx}, I_{zy}$ and $I_{zz}$ are the only surviving components of the inertia tensor. Corresponding components of the torque equation $\frac{d\textbf{L}}{dt}=\vec{\tau}$ (where $\vec\tau$ is the net external torque) are $$\tau_x=I_{zx}\alpha, \tau_y=I_{zy}\alpha~~ \text{ and}~~\tau_z=I_{zz}\alpha$$ where $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$.

Since the door is allowed to rotate only about $z$-axis, there must be rotational equilibrium about $x$ and $y$ axis i.e., $\tau_x=\tau_y=0$ but $\tau_z$ need not be zero. But $\tau_x=\tau_y=0$ imples $\alpha=0$. 
 Therefore, how can the equation $\tau_z=I_{zz}\alpha$ be satisfied for $\tau_z\neq 0$? Please help me spot the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the formulas incorrectly. Because you are in a rotating reference frame, the formula should be: $$\tau= \frac{d\vec L}{dt} + \vec \omega \times \vec L$$

Note that you are implicitly in a rotating reference frame because you assumed that: $$\frac{dI_{zx}}{dt}=\frac{dI_{zy}}{dt}=\frac{dI_{zz}}{dt}=0$$

If you would rather not work in a rotating reference frame, you have to include the time derivatives of the moment of inertia components in your equations.

Comment: My origin is fixed at any point on the axis passing through the hinges. all points on that axis are at rest, and therefore inertial. @Chris

Comment: @mithusengupta123 The door is moving, though. So either the xy plane rotates with the door (and you have a rotating reference frame) or it doesn't (and the moment of inertia tensor is time-dependent).